# Strange CSS behaviour with IE9 for submenu's DIV

Tags: css

I have this piece of code:

```
#bizMxp{position:absolute;min-width:140px;left:5px;z-index:100000;display:none;top:134px}
#bizMxp div{background-color:#fff;border:4px #6db03f solid;border-top:0;padding:15px;margin-top:20px}

$('.mxpbiz').hover(function(){$('#bizMxp').show('fast');},function(){$('#bizMxp').hide();}); 

<div id="mainMenu">
    <ul>
        <li<%=TabAttiva("mxpbiz",act)%>><a class="mxpbiz" href="#"><%=Lexicon("MXP BIZ")%></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="bizMxp">
        <div>
            <a href="/about"><%=Lexicon("About us")%></a><br/>
            <a href="/building"><%=Lexicon("The Building")%></a><br/>
            <a href="/where"><%=Lexicon("Location")%></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and it works perfectly with Chrome, FF and IE <= 8, but with IE9 submenu's div doesn't appear even if I am using absolute position and z-index... is there something I could have missed for IE9?....

Thanks in advance to everyone! :-)))

Cheers,
Luigi

Answer (score 0):

Which JS-Framework are you using? jQuery?

I tried out your code on JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/PaEk9/
It works on my IE9.

Maybe it's the problem of IE loading jQuery - i hat that Problem too. 
Try out to put your scripts at the bottom of the page or use `jQuery` instead of the dollar sign `$` on scripts on the outside of the DOM-Ready Method.

Use the DOM-Ready function Like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // your code, now using '$'
});
```

Maybe this helps.

Comment: HI spaark, first thank you for your answer but my .js code already contains jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ... } but still in IE8 and IE9 doesn't appear the div when in Chrome, FF, Opera and Safari works... and I have loaded latest jquery from googleapis archive: <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>.... any direction to check at?... thanks (you can even check www.mxpbusiness.com which is our production site with IE8/9 so you can see it has the issue)

Comment: Have you tried putting the script tags on the bottom of the page? It might sound a bit funky, but it could do the trick.

Comment: Yes I tried to put at bottom page, as you can see showing source of www.mxpbusiness.com but it still doesn't appear the div of submenus in IE... weird!...

Comment: I tried also to put an alert('...'); inside .hover() and I figured with IE it doesn't show even the alert message...which would mean it's something problem related to .hover() and compatibility with IE.... any directions?

Comment: I cant find a dropdown on your site. Maybe there are more than 1 elements with the same id `bizMxp`?